# How to maintain user session in clustered environment using spring security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

We have a login page and in SecurityConfig ,configured the CustomAuthenticationProvider,in this class storing the credentials in the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken object. We are capturing the User Credentials in Rest Controller .we have deployed the application in Clusterered environment .

If we login with credentails the request is going to one server and user details are coming in Rest Controller and in the same session if we refresh the page, the request is going to the other server so we are getting  null  user details.

```
@GetMapping("/myRentals")
    public  ModelAndView myDetails(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails user) {
        logger.info("user:"+user);
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthProvider;




    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

- Implement sticky session **or**
- Have a look at `Spring Session` where the Http Session can be backed by `JDBC`, `mongo` or `Redis` making it trivial to support clustered sessions. Spring's security's `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` will automatically use it

**Reference**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-jdbc.html

> Spring Session provides an API and implementations for managing a user’s session information while also making it trivial to support clustered sessions without being tied to an application container-specific solution

> Instead of using Tomcat’s HttpSession, we persist the values in the H2 database. Spring Session replaces the HttpSession with an implementation that is backed by a relational database. When Spring Security’s SecurityContextPersistenceFilter saves the SecurityContext to the HttpSession, it is then persisted into the H2 database.